# creating a makefile

Tags: c, makefile

So I have to create a makefile that would generate the application described below and make sure each generated file has its own rule.

For the makefile:
The first tool is flex, which takes a file called `spec.l` and generates a file called `lex.yy.c`. Another tool called bison expects a file `calledspec.y` and will generate the file `spec.tab.c`. If bison is called using the directives `-vd`, it will also generate a file called `spec.tab.h` (which is needed when compiling lex.yy.c). The two C files can be compiled into object files and then linked together with the yacc (-ly) and lex (-ll) libraries to generate the compiler (`a.out`.
The makefile you describe must generate the following commands if you were starting just with spec.l and spec.y:

```
flex spec.l
bison -vd spec.y
gcc -c lex.yy.c
gcc -c spec.tab.c
gcc spec.tab.o lex.yy.o -ly -ll
```

i am not sure where to start with this problem

edit: what i have so far

```
compiler: spec.tab.o lex.yy.o
gcc spec.tab.o lex.yy.o -ly –ll
lex.yy.c: spec.l
flex spec.l
spec.tab.c: spec.y
bison -vd spec.y
spec.tab.o: spec.tab.c
gcc -c spec.tab.c
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c spec.tab.h
gcc –c lex.yy.c
clean:
rm –f *.c *.o a.out
```

Comment: So, what's the problem then? What don't you understand here? Do you know about the built in rules? Can you proceed from there?

Comment: In case you haven't found it already here's a [link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/) to start you off.  A quick read of chapters 1-3 should get you going.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear: you do need to indent the command(s) associated with a dependency, and you need to leave a blank line between a command and the next dependency (otherwise, it thinks you're listing two or more commands to execute for a dependency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the make about the dependencies. For example, `lex.yy.c` depends on spec.l:

```
lex.yy.c: spec.l
    flex spec.l
```

The first line say `lex.yy.c` depends on `spec.l`. The second tells how to generate an updated version of `lex.yy.c` when `spec.l` is newer. We pretty much repeat that pattern with the other files. In the case of `calledspec.y`, we have two results that are produced from the same input/command. At least with GNU make, you can specify that like this:

```
spec.tab.c spec.tab.h: calledspec.y
    bison -vd calledspec.y
```

Then you pretty much repeat the process for dependencies of `.o` (or `.obj`, etc.) files on headers and C files:

```
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c spec.tab.h
   $(cc) -c lex.yy.c
```

One final note: unless you specify otherwise, make will build the *first* target specified in the makefile, so you normally want to arrange it with the final executable first, and other targets after that:

```
parser: lex.yy.o y.tab.o
    $(cc) -o parser lex.yy.o y.tab.o

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c spec.tab.h
    $(cc) -c lex.yy.c
```

And so on. This only applies to targets though, not to macros, so you'll typically see a few things like:

```
cflags = -O2
```

...at the beginning of a make file. Then the lines the invoke the compiler will use that, something like:

```
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c spec.tab.h
    $(cc) $(cflags) -c lex.yy.c
```

And when this is executed, the `cflags` macro will be expanded, so the command that gets executed is `gcc -O2 -c lex.yy.c` (and it predefines `cc` to the name of the compiler it normally expects to use, so Microsoft's make sets it to `cl`, GNU to `gcc`, etc.)